# Xcode clear mutable array in another class

Tags: arrays, xcode, class, mutable

In Xcode v6.4, I have have a calculator app with classes Calculator and Brain.  There's a mutable array in Brain called operandStack.  I would like to clear the contents of operandStack from the Calculator class.  Is this possible, and if so, how is it done?  I've tried (an get compiler errors):

```
[self.brain operandStack removeAllObjects];
```

and

```
[self.brain.operandStack removeAllObjects];
```

In Brain, I've declared the property @property (nonatomic, strong) NSMutableArray * operandStack; synthesized @synthesize operandStack = _operandStack;  Still getting the same compiler errors for [self.brain.operandStack removeAllObjects] in the Calculator class.

Comment: *What* compiler error do you get?

Answer (score 0):

```
[self.brain.operandStack removeAllObjects];
```

will work, but *only* if you declare the `operandStack` as a *property* in Brain.h:

```
@property (nonatomic, strong) NSMutableArray *operandStack;
```

(and include the synthesizer in Brain.m):

```
@synthesize operandStack;
```

I suspect that `operandStack` is currently a local or instance variable in Brain.

Comment: Please post your code in the question - it will be unreadable in the comments. Also, please post the compiler errors as well.

Comment: @Cheesehead1957 Keep in mind that the `brain` property within `self` must be the same instance of `Brain` that contains the array you wrote data to. It cannot be a fresh instance, so you'll have to pass the current class a reference to that object.